# How to get the notification?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Iam doing one application/In that i want to get the notification when the application is in sleep mode.First it check the condition if condition is satisfied then notiofication will rise.So for this,my code is

```
if ((f >= [babycrydefault floatForKey:@"keyToSlidervalue"])) {

    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotif.soundName = @"baby_cry-1.wav";
    localNotif.alertLaunchImage=@"baby.png";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
    [localNotif release];
}
```

when iam using this code iam not getting any notification.So please inform me if therer is any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First thing:** I don't think you want the code to execute while your app in the background :-) The code won't execute even if you want it to do.

**Second thing:** If you don't set the [`fireDate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/fireDate) the notification will be fired immediately. And if the notification fires while your app is running, the alert will not be displayed. Just the [`application:didReceiveLocalNotification:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3adidReceiveLocalNotification%3a) method in your app delegate will be triggred.

Comment: Main my requirment is first check the acceleration of x using UIAccelerometer.If that value cross the default value then nitification will be rise.For getting the acceleration of x,i write the code at - (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration  method.In this method also i write the above code.So when my application is in sleeping mode also it check the x value and rise the notification.

Comment: @naresh, Does this code works when the app in background? I don't think it will work

Comment: @naresh, That is the nature of iOS apps. And I am not "Sir" :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set fireDate of the notification.

It doesn't work as you want like whenever turns to sleep mode.

Check UILocalNotification developer reference.

Comment: sleep mode means when the application is not running sir

Comment: I get it. sorry for lame English skill.